# JSON.parse not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am using AJAX to get values from database. 
I am using

```
echo json_encode($writers);
```

in php.

in jscript when i call

```
document.getElementById("writer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

i get result

```
[{"name":"demo-1","user_id":"13","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"Atif Rauf
Alvi","user_id":"12","writing_level":"High
 School","writing_category":"Social
 Sciences,History,Mathematics and
 Economics,Nature,Health and
 Medicine,Creative
 writing","pri":3},{"name":"ffffo","user_id":"14","writing_level":"High
 School,College,Masters","writing_category":"Literature
 and Language,Social
 Sciences,Mathematics and
 Economics","pri":3},{"name":"mariam","user_id":"15","writing_level":"High
 School","writing_category":"Communications
 and Media,Religion and Theology,Life
 Sciences,Creative
 writing","pri":3},{"name":"ddd","user_id":"17","writing_level":"High
 School,College","writing_category":"Literature
 and Language,Art,Social
 Sciences,History,Law","pri":3},{"name":"maria","user_id":"16","writing_level":"High
 School","writing_category":"Art,Social
 Sciences,History,Law,Mathematics and
 Economics","pri":3},{"name":"Muhammad
 Zoyeb","user_id":"11","writing_level":"High
 School,College","writing_category":"Education,Tourism","pri":3},{"name":"wewe","user_id":"10","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"janea","user_id":"5","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"shazia","user_id":"4","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"s","user_id":"6","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"iuiui","user_id":"8","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"demo","user_id":"9","writing_level":"","writing_category":"","pri":3},{"name":"arsalan","user_id":"3","writing_level":"","writing_category":"Nature,Education,Health and Medicine,Communications and Media","pri":3}]
```

which is a valid json object

but when i use

```
var writer=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

i get error
can anyone plz help and explain how i can fix this

Thanks

i am using firefox and in firebug it just show error at JSON.parse

Comment: "i get error" is not a diagnosis.

Comment: What browser do you get the error in?

Comment: I got **no** errors when I took more than 2 seconds to test it.

Comment: IF you use it with IE < 8 you'll need to include json2.js to use JSON.parse, perhaps you already did it

Comment: i am using firefox and in firebug it just show error at JSON.parse

Comment: plz...i don't know what is wrong..i have been trying to fix this for hours...just tell me what i should be looking at

Comment: @shazia: quoting @DavidDorward: **What** error do you get?  What is the text of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Set appropriate content type in php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($writers);
```

Comment: While that should be done, it isn't clear that it isn't, and it wouldn't make a difference since the browser is going to end up with an unparsed string of text in xhr.responseText either way.

Comment: +1 because that should be done; -1 because it’s not relevant to his question in that it doesn’t fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your json using [jsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

I quickly copy and pasted your json into it and got some errors - make sure there are no line breaks in the json string as that will invalidate the json.